# Does $g^{k} x h^{k} = x$ for all $k \geq 1$ imply $g = h^{-1}$ and $gx = xg$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $g, h, x \in G$. Does $g^{k} x h^{k} = x$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ imply that $g$ and $h$ are inverse and that they commute with $x$?

If $g = h^{-1}$ and $gx = xg$ then $g^{k} x h^{k} = x$ will certainly always hold but I'm unsure why the converse should or shouldn't hold and I can't think of a counter example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to say $gxh=x$, since that implies $g^kxh^k=x$ for all other $k$.

And no, it doesn't imply $g=h^{-1}$, or that either of them commute with $x$. For instance, in $S_3$, we have
$$
(123)(12)(123)=(12)
$$
and $(123)\neq(123)^{-1}$, and $(123)(12)\neq(12)(123)$.

However, if we also know that $g=h^{-1}$, then that implies that $g$ and $x$ commute. And if we know that $g$ and $x$ commute, then that implies that $g=h^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you your answer and for the example, it is very helpful.